# Getting started with client certificates and PHP

Tags: php, iis, ssl, client-certificates

I'm a project manager on a internal website for my department, and I'm trying to set up an alternative to username/password authentication to the site. My impression is that the ideal method would be to use SSL client certificates on each authorized device to achieve this, but after trying to digest a few days worth of information and even purchasing a book on OpenSSL, I feel lost on how to even begin.

The gist of the setup is as follows:

- Website running on IIS 6
- PHP 5.2 with OpenSSL module installed
- Windows Server 2003
- Devices to login include Windows XP/Windows 7 PCs and Blackberry Devices
- Valid CA-Signed SSL Certificate currently installed on server and required for connection

What I'd like to do is request a client certificate from a connecting device; if not available, request username and password for LDAP authentication (this is currently working). Once authenticated, I'd like to give the user the ability to generate and download a client certificate for installation on the device for connection to this server without using the username/password combination.

I know I could do the same sort of "auto-login" using cookies, but I figured that security would be enhanced using this method instead, despite the more cumbersome configuration.

I was hoping that somebody around here could point me in the right direction to get started on something like this, or tell me if I'm headed in the wrong direction entirely to accomplish this. I'm sure there are plenty of gaps in my understanding, but every tutorial I've read so far has either been too generic to be useful or jumps in to a degree of complexity where I'm in over my head before I can get more than a few lines in.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can share!

Comment: By client certs do you mean self signed SSL certs? Or just AES 256 encrypted key files for transmission? Self signed SSL certs will have problems within most (if not all) browsers since self signed a cert is not a valid method of authentication and does is validate the cert at all.

Comment: If security is important, then you really want to be using a newer version of PHP than 5.2.  Any security will be for naught if it's bypassed by a known bug in a no-longer supported version of PHP.

Comment: We'll be upgrading past 5.2 this fall; I tried upgrading to 5.3/5.4, but had issues with either the SQL Server drivers or FastCGI or both, depending on which of the versions I tried moving to along with IIS6, but we're upgrading the whole server package in the next month or two.

Comment: And no, I don't mean self-signed SSL--I mean a client-installed certificate for user authentication. There is a properly installed and functional CA-signed SSL certificate for transmissions on https (port 443), but I want to authenticate the user using a certificate installed on his/her computer rather than using login credentials.

Comment: This sounds so dodgy, I mean you are trading a possibly stealable and possibly easily stealable (client compuer on insecure network, client computer insecure) inplace of a static requirement for user credentials. I just don't see how you intend to secure this type of login, I can't think of anyway to personally since you will be relying on the security of the weakest part of the chain, the client machine/device.

Comment: I appreciate your collective advice regarding the suitability of using the user certificate to automatically log in to the website in question. However, there are other numerous layers in place to protect the security of the login credentials. Firstly, each user is required by policy to have a strong password to log in to the computer or Blackberry in order to gain access to the device, which already gives the user access through AD to both the file structure navigated by the website as well as the database which the website parses for display. So adding another password does not increase...

Comment: ...security, it simply requires the user to log in twice to gain access to the same resources he would normally be able to access. The devices in question only have access to the site within the internal intranet--there is no access to the site or its resources available from outside the firewall, so the certificate would not do anybody any good without access to the VPN. My understanding was that client certificates may also be tied to specific hardware, unlike cookie authentication. I also restrict access to IP ranges, since they're all internal to our intranet.

Comment: For the record, Amazon's EC2 allows me to login simply using a certificate, and I don't know how many websites have "log me in automatically" cookies set I come across every day, so I figured that client certificates were abundantly cautious considering the context. But since nobody seems to have an answer, it looks like I have no choice but to use a cookie with a reasonable timeout to serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would put this as my answer because the more I read your question the more I think this IS my answer.

I would most definitely not do this. In order to allow AES encrypted "certs" or keyfiles to overcome the normal authentication process you would need to require the trust and integrity of one thing: the client machine/device.

This is impossible, you should never rely on the security or the safety of the clients machine and the data you have on their machine. A physcial password is a lot harder to steal than a physical file on the computer provided the user does not set "remember my password" in the browsers own password database on every site. That is why most physical passwrods are ascetained through stealing the websites database. Of course providing you know your stuff you can trust your own coding and hashing functions to provide the best security you have, more so than the client computer. If the clients cert was to be stolen there would NO way what-so-ever to know if it had, I agree the same is with passwords but as I stated above passwords are much harder to get at and even when you have the companies DB it is still much harder to crack the hashes providing they are done right.

I suppose to increase security you could say that every file should be restricted to an IP but then this defeats the point of going around the auth process because if you think about it, most of your users will be on dynamically assigned IPs from their ISPs. I know my ISP changes my IP every mid-night which means this file would no longer be valid anymore every single day which means once a day I would have to relog in anyway with my username and password.

This would be at the very least a security nightmare. Your user accounts would be just waiting to be hacked and is just unneeded bloat-ware ontop of your auth process.

However for your tightly controlled (if it is that tightly controlled, personally anything externally accessible even through mass auth is never tightly secured) intranet I would use PHP to generate my cert file using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-sign.php.

Now the key thing here is that you will want to store that cert on your side so you can evaluate it. For this you will want to use some parsing functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-parse.php on the client cert you get.

However cURL has its own client side SSL handler, look here:

[Client Certificates with LibCUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810432/client-certificates-with-libcurl?rq=1)

This will hopefully help,

Comment: Please see my above explanation. In a public context, I would tend to agree with you, but I'm working on a tightly controlled intranet which already requires AD authentication or Blackberry authentication to gain access to the devices in question, meaning the users have to log in repeatedly to gain access to resources they already have access to outside of the website.

Comment: @Strikefinder Ok I think I might have something that can help, edited the answer.